# Magento currency symbol position - Euro for English language

Tags: magento, currency

I am using Magento v1.9.1.0. and I have a problem with currency symbol position when having locale set to English and currency to Euro. It displays:

€24.10

I would like to show it like where locale is set to Slovenian and currency to Euro:

24.10 €

If I change 'lib/Zend/Locale/Data/en.xml' currency format, then it won't display like it should for US dollars currency symbol($).

Does anyone know the solution for that kind of problem?

Comment: Have you cleared all caches (file system folders, OPcache, Magento cache, ...) ?

Answer (score 0):

Clear all the cache, JavaScript/CSS too!

Comment: I have, the problem is actually not the problem anymore. If users from US visit page, it's ok to display €24.10. If users from European Union visit page, it should display 24.10€. It depends on the grammar of the language. That's what I read :)